# Exporting CSV with League/CSV doesn't encode umlauts

Tags: php, laravel, csv, utf-8, byte-order-mark

I am exporting a model in Laravel 5.7, using the [League/CSV](https://csv.thephpleague.com) package:

```
public function export(Request $request)
{
    $people = Person::all();
    $location = 'export.csv';
    $csv = Writer::createFromPath($location, 'w');
    $csv->setOutputBOM(Writer::BOM_UTF8);
    $csv->setDelimiter(';');
    foreach ($people as $person) {
        $csv->insertOne($this->serializePerson($person));
    }
    return response($location);
}

protected function serializePerson($person)
{
    return [
        $person->name,
        $person->age,
    ];
}
```

This creates the `export.csv` file ok, but any umlauts are rendered incorrectly (e.g. as `√∂`). I would have thought setting the BOM would have solved this. Does anyone have a solution?

EDIT: The problem was not the export, it was Mac Excel displaying the umlaut incorrectly. See my answer below.

Comment: did you try any of encoding method ? ex: `$reader->addStreamFilter('convert.iconv.ISO-8859-15/UTF-8');` ?

Comment: Adding that, the umlaut is no longer `√∂`, it is now `√É¬∂`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question was badly formulated, but I'll leave the answer here in case anyone else has the same problem. The file was in fact being correctly exported: if I opened it in a text editor the umlaut was correctly formed.

To get it working properly in Excel (on a Mac) I had to:

1. Open an empty worksheet
2. Data > Get External Data > Import Text File...
3. From the File origin dropdown, select "Unicode (UTF-8)"